# Django admin ModelForm, save calculated relateds

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm facing a problem with django admin in overwritter ModelForm's save() method.

models.py

```
class Reservation(models.Model):

    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_start = models.DateField()
    date_end = models.DateField()
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ReservationItem(models.Model):
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    unit_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    row_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    row_total_incl_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    reservation = models.ForeignKey(Reservation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')
    resource = models.ForeignKey(Resource, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The reservation items are derived from the service, by an availability query, so it've written a custom ModelForm for the admin.

admin.py

```
class ReservationModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        if 'service' in self.cleaned_data:
            self._check_availability()

        return self.cleaned_data

    def _check_availability(self):
        '''do some stuff an get items ad an array of ReservationItems instances created like this:
        ReservationItem(
            resource=avail_resource,
            quantity=resource_type.quantity,
            unit_price=resource.unit_price,
            unit_tax=resource.unit_price*resource.tax.percentage,
            row_total=resource.unit_price*resource_type.quantity,
            row_total_incl_tax=...
        )'''
        self.cleaned_data['items'] = items

    # then the save method
    def save(self, commit=True):
        reservation = super(ReservationModelForm, self).save(commit=commit)
        if not self.instance.id:
            service = self.cleaned_data.get('service')
            ....
            reservation.items.set(self.cleaned_data['items'], bulk=False)

         return reservation

class ReservationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   form = ReservationModelForm
```

Now all I get is an error: `save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'reservation'`.

But I can't save reservation first, because I need an atomic save, how can I solve?

Comment: Of course you need to save reservation first. How do you expect to know the ID to save in `ReservationItem`'s `Reservation` field otherwise? The save being atomic has nothing to do in there: atomic transactions are transactions encapsulated within a [`transaction.atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) context.

Comment: Ok you're right, but if the ReservationItems where an inlines, they'll be saved in a single transaction with parent Instance. I'd like to simulate the same thing

Comment: Easy: manually mark your save method as a single transaction, by adding the `@transaction.atomic(savepoint=False)` decorator above it. Or use a `with transaction.atomic(savepoint=False)` within the method. Or better yet: do it in your view, not in your form. Form should not get involved in the structure of the transaction.

Comment: I've tried to use `@transaction.atomic(savepoint=False)` but it doesn't work.
I need to do it in the form because the related fields must be validated (search for availability of resource or give validation error). Maybe the only solution is to replicate the validation part in the model and add there the relateds save part

Comment: You can mark your transaction as atomic in the view and let it invoke the form to do the actual job. It's as easy as decorating `post` method. Doing so will ensure everything done while handling the `POST` request will be wrapped in a single transaction. Be it one form, 10 forms or other random stuff.

Comment: @spectras it's not a simple form, but an admin form. I don't defined any view

Comment: You still define a view. Just because you use the default provided definition doesn't mean you don't use one. You can override it with one that wraps ths default one in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I'think I've found a solution. 
I've added an attribute to Reservation model `temp_items` and saved them in the model save() method with a transaction so i can extract and validate the items in the ModelForm save() and actually save in the Model save() method.
It seems to work great